# Play framework 2.4 scala REPL hangs on exit

Tags: scala, playframework

I try to use REPL for testing/debugging of my play framework application. I am playing with 2.4 version of Play. When I try to execute ":quit" on exit the application, after I called "new GuiceApplicationBuilder", the REPL hangs. Even if the GuiceApplicationBuilder failed with an exception.

Ctrl+C exits from activator completely, what I want to escape, because starting of activator is a little bi time consuming, when I try to do some small stuff with my application.

I suppose I must shutdown something before exiting, but couldn't figure what and how.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to say

```
play.api.Play.stop()
```

before quitting the console. It helps if the application is started with

```
new play.core.StaticApplication(new java.io.File("."))
```

The solution was found here:
https://yobriefca.se/blog/2014/07/11/working-with-play-apps-in-the-console/